# OctoberCMS: Trigger events doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms, octobercms-backend

After reading this (and others...) article ([link](http://octobercms.com/docs/ui/input-trigger)) on documentation I could not find an issue from my side...

I can't put the trigger event work... So here is my code:

//fields.yaml

```
fields:
    gallery:
        label: Galeria
        span: full
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        prompt: 'Add new item'
        type: repeater
        form:
            fields:
                type:
                    label: 'Select the type of a gallery item'
                    span: full
                    type: galleryplusvideoselect
                galleryplusvideo:
                    label: Gallery
                    span: full
                    oc.commentPosition: ''
                    type: galleryplusvideo
                    hidden: true
                    trigger:
                        action: show
                        field: type
                        condition: value[image]
```

//galleryplusvideoselect `_widget.htm` file

```
<div data-control="balloon-selector" class="control-balloon-selector">
    <ul>
        <li data-value="image" <?php if($type == "image") echo 'class="active"'; ?>>Image</li>
        <li data-value="video" <?php if($type == "video") echo 'class="active"'; ?>>Video</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="text" onkeyup="
            $(this).trigger('change')" <!-- <--- THIS IS ONLY TO REPRODUCE AN EXAMPLE FROM THE DOCUMENTATION -->
    name="<?=$name ?>" value="<?= $type ?>" />
</div>
```

[image]

I tryed to create a simple checkbox and textarea and create that trigger functionality **outside of a repeater**... but it isn't works... I could not found any type of JS "activation" so I don't know that I can to do to put this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `hidden: true`. The trigger `action: show` property will automatically hide your field, there is no need to double hide it. Cross posted in [OctoberCMS issue repository](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2715)